# Kubernetes port forwarding between host machine and nodes? #LoadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes, openfaas

I had 1 mission this weekend, get OpenFaas Cloud working on my home server.  Disclaimer, I know very little about Kubernetes.

I have been following the OpenFaas Cloud guide here.  The slack group has been very helpful but I still stuck:
https://github.com/openfaas-incubator/ofc-bootstrap

So I have a kubernetes cluster on a host machine(Ubuntu 16.04).  Its IP is 192.168.0.98.

I would like to map port 80 on my host(192.168.0.98) so that it sends the traffic to the LoadBalancer(10.104.107.60)

```
kubernetes                                   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      6h30m

nginxingress-nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.104.107.60   <pending>     80:31166/TCP,443:30837/TCP   4h42m

nginxingress-nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.97.123.87    <none>        80/TCP                       4h42m
```

The LoadBalancer is running nginx-ingress, when I asked about the port forwarding on the OpenFaas group they mentioned:

Nginx -> router -> auth -> gateway -> function

> On the cloud a load balancer gets an IP and you set the DNS then
>   accessing the load balancer corresponds to nginx You are on premise so
>   you need to edit your nginx config so that it binds to port 80/443 or
>   use HAProxy on the host to forward to the nginx you have running on
>   the node inside the cluster.

This went a little beyond my skillset :(

Comment: How did you set up the local cluster. Is it running inside a VM of some kind?

Comment: Yes it’s running on a hyper-v, it’s a single node cluster

Comment: You would have to do this via Hyper-V then, Kubernetes is not involved until the packets actually get to the VM, networking between the host network and the VM is all up to Hyper-V

Comment: The hyper-v to host is all sorted, real server is .124, vm is .98. Packets to get the vm fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quite easily change the LoadBalancer service type to NodePort one, by upgrading nginx-ingress-controller`s corresponding helm chart:

```
helm upgrade nginxingress stable/nginx-ingress --set \
controller.service.type=NodePort --recreate-pods
```

You should be able now to hit the openfaas gateway via http://localhost_ip:node_port/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Hyper-V level port forwarding is set up as you mentioned, you'll want to switch the main Service from a LoadBalancer to a NodePort and either hardwire a particular node port or forward whichever happens to be picked.